# Keep a Base64 <img> in small thumbnail and original aspect

Tags: html, css, image

Have an image applications, on the left is a narrow column contains many `<img>` thumbnails whose content is **Base64**, like `<img src="dataimage/jpeg;base64,...">`. Users click on one will display a much bigger image at right.

HTML attribute `height="##"` is very useful to keep the thumbnails in a small size even when it's clicked on. On the contrary, `style="height:##; max-width:##; max-height:##"` will change a thumbnail into a full-scale image and bump others over the cliff.

Most of the images are portrait, a few are wide landscape format. You can see a single `height` attribute is not good enough. So I add a `width`

`<img src="dataimage/jpeg:base64;..." height="50" width="50">`

it does help locking the width but turns all thumbnails into 50x50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set static `width` and `height` and add `object-fit: contain;` to keep the aspect ratio:

```css
input
{
  display: none;
}

.container
{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.thumbs,
.container
{
  display: flex;
}

.thumbs
{
  flex-direction: column;
}

label > img
{
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  object-fit: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.full
{
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.full > img
{
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(100px);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  transition: opacity 0.4s, filter 0.3s;
  order: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

input:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ .full > img:nth-of-type(1),
input:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ .full > img:nth-of-type(2),
input:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ .full > img:nth-of-type(3),
input:checked:nth-of-type(4) ~ .full > img:nth-of-type(4)
{
  display: initial;
  opacity: 1;
  order: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="t1" type="radio" name="thumb">
  <input id="t2" type="radio" name="thumb">
  <input id="t3" type="radio" name="thumb" checked>
  <input id="t4" type="radio" name="thumb">
  <div class="thumbs">
    <label for="t1"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj"></label>
    <label for="t2"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fl-GT6w3Ls6RT4vYnbkuYUyLY3lZJH8VtZ7xzxiym9YYaoVRCnZehdz6Icd0oAf6i3H9-O5cCNs6eunlxWr_Csstgsb98DdzNdLFBOlhw9NUfHdyuQjI=w768-h1024-n-l50-sg-rj"></label>
    <label for="t3"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9pPCK70Rw0k3wethMHb1qMaIB0VjeWLy57vYgSzKbF7oJuvO2nA0Nakk-95cvibWUDcEhYkfCKvdPKT03tXZd4M5jdhIEibLO9qw-XE=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj"></label>
    <label for="t4"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aS2Up3osDMLTua1vXPTqnXko13KbIAmB0nQ44AP_IFTEt-VjUa6Tz2MC9jdH11bsZfjdiR8z4HbnxvhmmxSU1swKrtjc5PXreP6i=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="full">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fl-GT6w3Ls6RT4vYnbkuYUyLY3lZJH8VtZ7xzxiym9YYaoVRCnZehdz6Icd0oAf6i3H9-O5cCNs6eunlxWr_Csstgsb98DdzNdLFBOlhw9NUfHdyuQjI=w768-h1024-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9pPCK70Rw0k3wethMHb1qMaIB0VjeWLy57vYgSzKbF7oJuvO2nA0Nakk-95cvibWUDcEhYkfCKvdPKT03tXZd4M5jdhIEibLO9qw-XE=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aS2Up3osDMLTua1vXPTqnXko13KbIAmB0nQ44AP_IFTEt-VjUa6Tz2MC9jdH11bsZfjdiR8z4HbnxvhmmxSU1swKrtjc5PXreP6i=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fully workable sample! Just a side note for others, it requires `class` to work, `style` won't.

Comment: @Jeb50 Why is that? Do you mean if `<img>` has `width` / `height` attributes the CSS sizing won't work?

Comment: I initially tested by removing attribute `height` and `width` then using in-line `style`, not working so have to use `class`.

Comment: In-line styles via `style` attribute can have any style, it have higher priority than CSS  (unless `!important` was used) and will only be applied to one particular element.

Comment: correct, that's why it was first tested with `style`. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you'd like the thumbnails to not go above 50px in height but the images to be within the narrow column width wise and to maintain their aspect ratios.

You can do this by using the CSS contain value on the object-fit property. The width and height of the img is set to be the width of the narrow column and a height of 50px (for example) and it will then be completely within those bounds, maintaining aspect ratio.

I don't think that the images being base64 or jpgs or... should make any difference.

```css
.narrowcolumn {
  width: 40px;
  /* set this to whatever is required */
  display: inline-block;
}

.narrowcolumn img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  /* set this to whatever you require */
  object-fit: contain;
  padding: 1px 0;
  /* added for demo just to separate them a bit */
}
```

```html
<div class="narrowcolumn">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/300/300">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/200">
</div>
```

Comment: The other one provides more detailed example was chosen as the Answer. But excellent direction! Given an Up vote. Thank you.